# Error when exporting the result of a valid command as a bash variable

Tags: macos, bash, amazon-web-services, command-line, environment-variables

I'm trying to export the result of a command line as en environment variable. Here is how I'm doing it:

```
group_id=$(aws ec2 describe-security-groups --filters Name=group-name,Values=${group_name} \
  | jq '.["SecurityGroups"][0].GroupId' \
  | sed -e 's/^"//'  -e 's/"$//'
)
```

However when I run the bash file, I get the following error:

```
Error parsing parameter '--filters': Expected: '=', received: 'EOF' for input:

 ^
```

The command is valid, as it works when I try it directly from the command line. Any idea why I'm getting this error?

Comment: What exactly are you typing when calling the file?

Comment: I call this way `./mybashfile option`, its an executable i've already `chmod +x mybashfile`

Comment: What do you have at the top of the file? You probably need to include `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: Yeah sure I've this shebang, my bash works fine, it's only when I add the command above that I get an error when running it

Answer (score 0):

I had to put the whole command in one single line, I don't know why the `\` was causing a problem!